# Spark functions.coalesce not working on mongodb collections but works on CSVs

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

### Coalesce logic working fine on csv

`e1.csv`

```
id,code,type
1,,A
2,,
3,123,I
```

`e2.csv`

```
id,code,type
1,456,A
2,789,A1
3,,C
```

```
        Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").load("C:\\Users\\System2\\Videos\\folder\\e1.csv");
        Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").load("C:\\Users\\System2\\Videos\\folder\\e2.csv");


        Column[] coalescedColumns = 
                //df1.columns().stream()
              Stream.of(df1.columns())
               .map(name -> functions.coalesce(df1.col(name),df2.col(name)).as(name))
                 .toArray(Column[]::new);

        Dataset<Row> newDS = df1.as("a").join(df2.as("b")).where("a.id== b.id").select(coalescedColumns);
```

I can't able to apply this logic on mongo collection

### what I have tried on mongo collection

```
String host= "localhost";
        String port = "27017";
        String DB = "Provider_Golden";
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("cust data").setMaster(mst);
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .config(conf)
                .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://"+host+":"+port+"/"+DB+".T")
                .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri","mongodb://"+host+":"+port+"/"+DB+".T")
            //  .config("spark.exeuctor.extraJavaOptions","-XX:+UseG1GC")
                .getOrCreate();

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

         // Create a custom ReadConfig for e1
        Map<String, String> readE1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        readE1.put("collection", "e1");
        readE1.put("readPreference.name", "secondaryPreferred");
        ReadConfig readConfig_E1 = ReadConfig.create(spark).withOptions(readE1);


        Dataset<Row>  e1 = MongoSpark.load(jsc,readConfig_E1).toDF();



        // Create a custom ReadConfig for e2
        Map<String, String> readE2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        readE2.put("collection", "e2");
        readE2.put("readPreference.name", "secondaryPreferred");
        ReadConfig readConfig_E2 = ReadConfig.create(spark).withOptions(readE2);

        Dataset<Row>  e2 = MongoSpark.load(jsc,readConfig_E2 ).toDF();


        Column[] coalescedColumns = 

                Stream.of(e1.columns())
               .map(name -> functions.coalesce(e1.col(name),e2.col(name)).as(name))
                 .toArray(Column[]::new);

        Dataset<Row> goldenCopy = e1.as("a").join(e2.as("b")).where("a.id == b.id").select(coalescedColumns);
```

### Expected result (works on csv file ,same logic)

```
+---+----+----+
| id|code|type|
+---+----+----+
|  1| 456|   A|
|  2| 789|  A1|
|  3| 123|   I|
+---+----+----+
```

### Actual result

```
+--------------------+----+---+----+
|                 _id|code| id|type|
+--------------------+----+---+----+
|[5cab0a4bb12dfd5f...|    |  1|   A|
|[5cab0a4bb12dfd5f...| 123|  3|   I|
|[5cab0a4bb12dfd5f...|    |  2|    |
+--------------------+----+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `mongoimport` your CSVs you may get empty string instead of `null`.[refer](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/195).So your `coalesce` works on `null` values not on empty string `''`.I believe you have to replace `""` to `null`.

```
 Dataset<Row>  e1 = MongoSpark.load(jsc,readConfig_E1).toDF();

        String[] columns = e1.columns();

        Dataset<Row> e1_NULLs= replaceNull(e1, columns );

        e1_NULLs.show();
```

`Replace_null function`

```
private static Dataset<Row> replaceNull(Dataset<Row> df, String[] cl) {
        for(String g : cl){
      ///neglecting mongo id
            if(!g.equals("_id")){

                df = df.withColumn(g,
                             functions.when(df.col(g).equalTo(""),null).otherwise(df.col(g))
                        );  
            }
        }
        return df.drop("_id");
    }
```

Apply `coalesce` on newly created datasets with nulls, perform this `replaceNull` on two datasets